# Why do I have to remove added subviews for UITableViewCell but not in a Subclass of UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, view, uitableview, tableview, subview

So I was adding labels and such to my UITableViewCell and when I added the subviews, I learned I needed to remove them or else they would remain glitchy...

I can understand that, but now when I am using a custom cell class, I no longer have to remove the added subviews. Why is this?

I simply initialized the label in the my custom cell class's init method, with a custom frame (not through IB).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you left one extra ref. Note that [[foo alloc] init] return a ref with +1 and adding subview adds one more ref.

Normal way to use addsubview is to pass it autoreleased ref like this (example).

```
[cell addSubview:[UILabel label:args]];
```

or this (example):

```
[cell addSubview:[[[Foo alloc] init] autorelease]];
```

Comment: This is not very clear to me... That is the way I added the subview.